# Where to get old systrace(platform tools) for SDK 17 and less?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, android-sdk

I am using an older Android device which uses Android 4.2.2.
Older devices can not use the newer CPU profiler so I want to use `systrace`.

I tried using the current version of systrace but got the warning:

```
"Device SDK version < 18 (Jellybean MR2) not supported. Your device SDK version is 17."
```

I found the links below, which gave me a link to download tools and adb, but I can not see systrace anywhere:

- [Where can I download an older version of the Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk/27043655#27043655)
- [Download & Install Android tools, platform-tools, build-tools (Offline)](http://venomvendor.blogspot.jp/2012/03/download-install-offline-platform-tools.html)

Where can I find the old systrace?

Comment: Check the [repo maintained by Izzy, one of our mods](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads). Please confirm so that I request Izzy to post as answer

Comment: @beeshyams I downloaded a couple of the windows adb binaries but couldn't see systrace.

Comment: Okay, thought it would be included

Comment: Note that systrace was integrated into DDMS in ADT 21: http://tools.android.com./download/adt-21-preview so you would need to download the full tools zip from your first link.

Answer (score 0):

I found the download page for SDK version 17 through https://web.archive.org.
https://web.archive.org/web/20120327202205/http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

After downloading, there was no platform_tools folder, so I checked tools to see adb_has_moved.txt which suggests that android.bat should be run to generate the folder. After execution, the SDK manager opens with the option to download platform_tools. This downloads platform_tools with systrace inside to the folder.

- Unfortunately, systrace seems to be outputting the following error:

  `C:/Python27/python.exe ./systrace.py --time=5 -o mynewtrace.html
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./systrace.py", line 212, in <module>
  main()
  File "./systrace.py", line 124, in main
  ready = select.select([adb.stdout, adb.stderr], [], [adb.stdout, adb.stderr]
  select.error: (10093, '`